# strcpy / strncmp segmentation fault in struct fileds

Tags: c, struct, char, strncpy, strncmp

I'm trying to add a new node to a struct with a char* field (word)

> **Definition of listT:**

```
enum boolean {false, true};
struct list {
    enum boolean sorted;
    union{
        int words;
        char *word;
    };
    struct list* next;
    struct list* previous;
};
typedef struct list listT;
```

add_word_node function is being called by main as: `add_word_node(read_word, list_head)`
where `read_word` is given by the user with scanf. Word is being pass as a string but after strncpy there is no terminating byte.

```
>Debugger:
     add_word_node (word=0xbffff0fa "ally", head=0x804c038) at prog.c    
>Debugger:
     (gdb) p newnode->word


     $2 = 0x804c068 "allyP\224\373\267\377\377\377\377" 




 listT *add_word_node(char word[], listT *head) {
    listT *newnode;
    listT *curr = NULL;//sorted
    //listT *prev;//sorted

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(listT)); /* allocate new node and check */
    newnode->word = malloc(sizeof(char)* WORDLEN);
    strncpy(newnode->word, word, strlen(word));
    //newnode->word = strndup(word, strlen(word));


    if (newnode == NULL) {
        return (NULL);
    }

    if (head->sorted == false){ //eisagwgh sto telos ths listas
        newnode->next = head;
        head->previous->next = newnode;
        newnode->previous = head->previous;
        head->previous = newnode;
    }else {
        if(head->next == head){
            newnode->next = head;
            newnode->previous = head;
            head->next = newnode;
            head->previous = newnode;

        }else{
            for (curr = head->next; curr->next != NULL; curr = curr->next){//for( curr = head->next; ;){
                if(curr == NULL) break;
                if(strncmp(curr->word,newnode->word,strlen(word)) > 0) break;
                //else curr= curr->next;
            }
            if(strncmp(curr->word,newnode->word,strlen(word))== 0){
                return(curr);
            }
            newnode->next = curr;
            newnode->previous = curr->previous;
            newnode->previous->next = newnode;
            newnode->next->previous = newnode;
        }
    }

    return (newnode);

}
```

I have read some other topics about this problem and I changed the function to use word[] instead of char* but it still doesn't work. Please tell me if you need more info.
Also, when I use strndup, it sometimes work without any error.

Comment: Are you sure when `curr = head->next` that head->next is not NULL? Because when that is the case curr->word will give seg fault for sure.. Yes that is the problem.

Comment: I added an if statement to break the for loop in case curr == NULL but still get the same seg fault.

Comment: In your `for` loop, I'd check the validity of `curr`, and not just reassign it in an `else`: `for (cur = head->next; curr->next; curr = curr->next)` would be a little safer

Comment: I changed as you suggested but I still get seg.
`for (curr = head->next; curr->next != NULL; curr = curr->next)
if(curr == NULL) break;
if(strncmp(curr->word,newnode->word,strlen(word)) > 0) break;`

Comment: Post definition of `listT`

Comment: `enum boolean {false, true};
struct list {
 enum boolean sorted;
 union{
  int words;
  char *word;
 };
 struct list* next;
 struct list* previous;
};
typedef struct list listT;`

Comment: `strncpy(newnode->word, word, strlen(word)+1);` is wrong.

Comment: Could you please explain what is wrong with this line?

Comment: Function `add_word_node` is never called, so nothing could possibly happen in this program. In addition, structure `listT` is not defined, so this code cannot even compile.

Comment: @user3163175: it is false safety. It does exactly the same thing as `strcpy(newnode->word, word);` and offers no additional "protection" (strncpy never does) Also the definition for your `List` structure is missing. (is newnode->word a pointer or an array? it could even be a Variable Length Array)

Comment: @barak manos listT is defined and I posted it 3 comments above. Also this is a function of a program not a single program.

Comment: Why didn't you put it in the question, where it belongs?

Comment: Well first of all, post the relevant information within the question, not in comments. Second, it didn't occur to me that this function was your entire program. I was trying to politely imply that you have not posted all the relevant information required in order to answer your question. You should at least show what parameters you are calling this function with.

Comment: @barakmanos I hope I didn't offend you (I didn't mean to). You are right and I apologizing for not being clear enough i will add more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say you have a `char *word` then this pointer should be allocated memory

```
newnode->word = malloc(sizeof(char) * (WORDLEN+1)); /* Please access the structure elements accordingly */
```

Memory should be allocated to the pointer before writing something to it.

Comment: Doens't this: `newnode = (listT *) malloc(sizeof(listT) + WORDLEN);` allocate memory for char* word?

Comment: @user3163175 I can't see what is WORDLEN in the code but it is not needed just allocate memory to your struct and allocated memory the pointer withing the structure

Comment: Thanks for the info. I changed it but I don't think that this solves the problem since WORDLEN wach bigger than the actual length of words.

Comment: @user3163175 PLease allocate memory to hold the `WORDLEN` Check edits

Comment: I did but nothing changed

Comment: @user3163175 Do you still see segmentation fault? `WORDLEN + 1` to hold the NULL terminator?

Comment: I was wrong. I changed malloc but now the word is being passed as i.e. "alpha" but there is no \0 after strncpy

Comment: I added an example in question

Comment: @user3163175 You NULL terminate it manually. Add `memset(newnode->word,'\0',(WORDLEN+1))`

Comment: Memset wasn't working as I wanted (It added \0 at the begginig) but since word is an array I just added it in the end. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

To expand @Gopi's answer a bit:

Your statement

```
newnode = (listT *) malloc(sizeof(listT) + WORDLEN);
```

allocates memory to the pointer `newnode`. This means that, for example if `WORDLEN` is the same as `sizeof(listT)`, then you will be allocating memory for two `listT` elements for `newnode`. This is similar to, say, `char *ptr = malloc(2);` which will allocate memory for two `char` elements for `ptr`.

TL;DR: This `WORDLEN` memory will NOT be allocated to `newnode->word`, it is allocated to `newnode`, and that's that. To fix your problem, you must allocate memory to `newnode->word` separately. `newnode` does not need that memory, but `newnode->word` does.

`strndup()` works because it allocates the memory for you.

If you still struggle to understand this, you may have some misconceptions on pointers.

`newnode->word` is a pointer. It has a fixed size on a certain machine (e.g. 8 bytes). For simplicity assume `listT` is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    char *word;
} listT;
```

Then when you allocate memory, you only need to allocate 8 bytes to `newnode` so that it can hold one pointer, and then you need to allocate memory to that pointer, which will be used to store some characters.

---

Although not related to your problem, I would also like to point out that you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()`. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3488231)